# Matlab PCA scree plot - which variable was most important?

Tags: matlab, pca

Less of a coding question, more of a "have I understood what I'm doing?" question.

Conducting some PCA analysis of some data with up to 7 variables, and I want a scree plot to show me how much each variable affects the variance in the data.

I make a scree plot by using:

```
    [coeff,score,latent,~,explained] = pca(X);

    bar(explained)
```

My understanding from the documentation is that the outputs are all sorted "columns are in descending order of component variance", so like, how do I know which variable actually accounts for the most variance? Like my data has 7 variables, so how do I know it's variable 3 and not variable 6? If it didn't sort it it'd be really obvious, but with said sorting in descending order how do I know?

[Matlab PCA documentation](https://au.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html#btjpztu-1)

Answer (score 0):

When you compute PCA, you get a new coordinate system out. Each dimension in this new coordinate system explains a certain amount of the variance of the input, and are sorted according to that quantify.

`coeff(:,1)` is the direction of the first PCA axis, in terms of the input axes. This axis is aligned with the largest variance in your data.  `explained(1)` is the fraction of the total variance in the data represented by this axis.

So, `explained` is sorted in the same way as the columns of `coeff`, and is related to them. It does not refer to the input variables.

Comment: Thank you for your explaination, but you've sort of restated the issue I have. When you say "So, explained is sorted in the same way as the columns of coeff, and is related to them. It does not refer to the input variables." I NEED to relate the output of the PCA to the input variables, otherwise it doesn't mean anything, right? How would one do that?

Comment: I guess to put it another way, when you say "coeff(:,1) is the direction of the first PCA axis, in terms of the input axes" does that mean that if coeffs are like 0.7,0.2,0.1, then input axes 1 accounts for most of the variation?

Comment: Or I guess to put it yet another way, I'm fairly confident that I understand what PCA does, in the same way I understand that mathematically 2+2 = 4, but what's important to me is "am I adding 2 apples to 2 apples to get 4 apples; or 2 apples to 2 oranges to get 4 fruit." Like it's the meaning of the output I'm trying to grasp.

Comment: If you want to know how much variance each input variable has, just use `var` to compute the variance, you don’t need PCA for that. In your example, the new axis 1 is 0.7 times the first input variable, plus 0.2 times the second, plus 0.1 times the third. This is a new variable, and it explains `explained(1)` fraction of the total variance. This accounts for (and assumes) correlation between the input variables. You cannot derive input variable variance from the PCA.

Comment: I'm sorry Cris I'm not sure you've understood - I'm not after input variable variance.

Comment: Let's say I have data with 3 columns, x,y & z, and the scree plot shows pca1 explains 70% of the total variance. How do I know which variable, x, y or z has the greatest influence on PCA1?

Comment: Having 3 scalar values u,v and w, how would you evaluate which has the greatest influence on the variance?